# How to set background image to buttons in silverlight in the codebehind file of WP7 application

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, button, background-image

I would like tho know how to add an image to a button dynamically in the code rather than in xaml. Someone had suggested to proceed the following way

```
ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images/myImage.png", UriKind.Relative)); 
AlphabetButton.Background = brush;
```

but BitmapImage is not detected by the intellisense though i can find BitConvertor and Bitmapcache.
If this is not the method, how else would i set the background images

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code:

```
ImageBrush background = new ImageBrush();
background.ImageSource = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri(@"SplashScreenImage.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
Button1.Background = background;
```

Works as expected. BitmapImage is in System.Windows.dll which should already be in your WP7 project.

Comment: thank you.. :)    I added using.windows.media.imaging to the namespace. And BitmapImage can now be accessed.

Answer (score 1):

I find that it is much easier and simpler to just put an Image control behind the button that you want to display and leave the button with a transparent background.

This removes the need to create a separate brush for the button and also makes it more extensible if you want to add test over the image.  IMHO

Comment: Thank you. Im fairly new to WP and Silverlight and C#. So could you give little more of help on image control. Yea I'm creating separate brush everytime and it is indeed odd.